# Python Pandas Library Resample By Truncate Date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, resampling

use python3 library [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), i have a data in excel file like this

```
 Id |          Date           |  count
----+-------------------------+-----------
 1  |   '2019/10/01 10:40'    |   1
----+-------------------------------------
 2  |   '2019/10/01 10:43'    |   2
----+-------------------------------------
 3  |   '2019/10/02 10:40'    |   3
----+-------------------------------------
 4  |   '2019/10/05 10:40'    |   4
----+-------------------------------------
 5  |   '2019/10/08 10:40'    |   5
----+-------------------------------------
 6  |   '2019/10/09 10:40'    |   6
----+-------------------------------------
 7  |   '2019/10/15 10:40'    |   7
```

i want group by this example by week and time. for example my needed result is:

```
 Id |       Week Time         |  count
----+-------------------------+-----------
 1  |   'Tuesday 10:40'       |   1
----+-------------------------------------
 2  |   'Tuesday 10:43'       |   2
----+-------------------------------------
 3  |   'Wednesday 10:40'     |   3
----+-------------------------------------
 4  |   'Saturday 10:40'      |   4
----+-------------------------------------
 5  |   'Tuesday 10:40'       |   5
----+-------------------------------------
 6  |   'Wednesday 10:40'     |   6
----+-------------------------------------
 7  |   'Tuesday 10:40'       |   7
```

and after resample by pandas i get this result:

```
        Week Time         |  sum  | count | avg 
 -------------------------+-------+-------+---------
    'Tuesday 10:40'       |   14  |   3   | 4.66
 -------------------------+-------+-------+---------
    'Tuesday 10:43'       |   2   |   1   | 2.00
 -------------------------+-------+-------+---------
    'Wednesday 10:40'     |   9   |   2   | 4.50
 ---------------------------------+-------+---------
    'Saturday 10:40'      |   4   |   1   | 4.00
```

can i get this result from resample method of pandas library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need custom format of datetimes by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and then aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%A %H:%M')
#if necessary remove trailing '
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.strip("'")).dt.strftime('%A %H:%M')

df = df.groupby('Date', sort=False)['count'].agg(['sum','count', 'mean'])
print (df)
                 sum  count      mean
Date                                 
Tuesday 10:40     13      3  4.333333
Tuesday 10:43      2      1  2.000000
Wednesday 10:40    9      2  4.500000
Saturday 10:40     4      1  4.000000
```

Comment: thank you for solution, this means that i can't use from resample method?

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani - If want aggregate by dyas like `Tuesday` and similar then not.

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani - resample working only with datetimes, not strings